# How to get rid of duplicate class errors in Intellij for a Mavenized project using Lombok

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a Maven managed Lombok project and I use Intellij. After building, I always get lots of errors in Intellij about duplicate classes because of the generated sources in `target/generated-sources/delombok`. Is there something I can do to git rid of these errors? Right now I just delete the target folder, but this is really irritating to have to do.

I have the standard configuration in Maven and the Lombok source code in is in `src/main/lombok`:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>delombok</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>lombok-needs-tools-jar</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.8.0</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8</version>
                            <scope>system</scope>
                            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using delombok? For just using Lombok, you only need the [(provided) dependency on lombok](https://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/index.html).

Comment: I want to generate Javadoc that includes the Lombokified methods. For that, I need to generate sources so that I can run javadoc against those.

Comment: I am not a mvn guru, but I'm pretty sure you can configure to delombok to a different directory (configure `lombok.outputDirectory`) and instruct javadoc to use that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution suggested by Andrey Dernov [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003367400-How-to-exclude-duplicated-classes-from-out-directory-from-compilation-when-using-gradle-and-tools-like-lombok-google-protobuf-and-swagger) worked for me with Maven.

Enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner > Enable "Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven" option

Comment: This solution didn't work for me IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 on Windows. I still get duplicated sources.

Answer (score 22):

According to [delombok goal documentation](http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/delombok-mojo.html): the default output directory is:

```
${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/delombok
```

I have found an JetBrains Team member [comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206849665/comments/206345015) stating that:

> IDEA automatically excludes the build 'target' folder, providing that there are no generated sources under it, otherwise it excludes all sub-folders but the generated.
>
> If you have some generated code or build artifacts that you want being excluded, you may put it under the 'target' folder.

This means that `/generated-sources` directory is by default not excluded and if you intend on excluding some files you should place them under parent `/target` directory and NOT under `/generated-sources`.

To achieve this you should configure the plugin and provide non-default `<outputDirectory>`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.18.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>delombok</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
        <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will stop IDEA from yielding `Duplicate class found in (...)` warnings.

Comment: I will try to test this out sometime in the next month. I am going to be on vacation for a while, work is crazy and I actually refactored the project I was working to not use delombok a while back because these errors were confusing to people who were working with my codebase.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 on Windows. I still get duplicated sources.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Krzusiek's solution but IntelliJ would still mark my source files from src/main/java as duplicated.

After many failed attempts to tweak the `lombok-maven-plugin` I eventually decided to get rid of the `delombok` folder after compilation. That folder only server as an intermediary stage for compilation (in my case I needed it to use lombok with AspectJ compiler via the `aspectj-maven-plugin`) and there's no real need to keep it once your source files have been compiled.

Manually removing the `delombok` folder after each compilation is a real bummer, so I just configured an additional execution of the `maven-clean-plugin` which would specifically target the `delombok` folder.

Your POM should contain:

```
<build>

    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/delombok</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <!-- will delombok source files into /target/generated-sources/delombok -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>delombok</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- other plugins bound to compile phase should go here -->

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>delombok-removal</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/com</directory> <!-- assuming your root package is something like com.mycompany -->
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to remove generated-source from sources. I could do it from Project Structure -> Select from the list of packages and in right hand side find the folders that are being used to derive sources for that package. If you find generated-source in that list remove it.

Comment: This solution looked like it worked for me as it not longer showed the classes as duplicated, until I ran tests and they were still duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to apply to Krzysiek's answer - move `generated_sources` directory under `target` so it will be `/target/generated_sources`. The next step is to unmark given directory as generated sources root. Then you have to right click on given project in Intellij, select `Maven` and then `Reload project`. After that do the same but this time go `Maven -> Generate Sources and Update Folders`. If you have multi module project and one module depends on each other i.e. module `A` depends on `B` then you have to start with `B` first.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 on Windows. Even if I unmark as generated sources it gets marked again automatically.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to unmark the folder with generated sources in Intellij and will be fine.

Comment: Consider including how to do it to give a useful answer.